# How do I make a 'Perfect 8'?

Tags: blood-brothers

My question is, say I wanted to make a perfect Firuch Snowcaller II

Would I have the same result if I evolve them using the following methods (Master + Pawn -> New Familiar):

1. lv70 Firuch Iceblood + lv70 Firuch Iceblood -> lv70 Firuch Iceblood II
2. lv1 Firuch Iceblood + Lv70 Firuch Iceblood -> lv1 Firuch Iceblood II which I then train up to lv70.

Which Firuch Iceblood II would have the higher max stats at level 70? or would they be the same?

If someone can answer this question, I'll be able to do the rest of the things :)

Comment: Hi DodgeNDive, i have changed my answer entirely, let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Make a "Perfect" Familiar you have to do the following.(Method found on the Blood brothers wiki's evolution [page](http://bloodbrothersgame.wikia.com/wiki/Evolution#Achieving_Max_Stats))

> Achieving Max stats
>
> - Requires 8 1-star versions of the Familiar.
> - Four of those must be leveled to Max,  and then used as the Seed for the other Four.
> - Two of the Resulting 2-Star Familiars should then be leveled to Max (This will give max Stats for the 2-Star version), and then used as
>     Seed for the two others.
> - One of the resulting 3-Star Familiars should be leveled to max (yielding the 3-Star Max Stats), and used as the Seed for the other.
> - The resulting 4-Star Familiar, when leveled completely will have Max Stats.

It is important to note that when a seed is on it's max level the spawn will inherent 10% of it's stats instead of just 5%.

Extra info can be found on the [Blood Brothers wiki](http://bloodbrothersgame.wikia.com/wiki/Evolution)

So in your case your second method would yield the max stats.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you done this before and compared?

Lets say the max stats for Firuch Iceblood is 500,
While the max stats for Firuch Iceblood II is 1000.

My thoughts for now is that option 1 would have 550 stats (500+ 10% of 500) while option 2 would have 1050 stats, as it receives the 10% and then you're able to level it as a Firuch II to get the 1000 stats it would normally have.

Further thoughts?

Comment: I will expand/improve my answer tomorrow. I just need to get my references sorted out.

Comment: @Josefvs I don't think you quite understood what I was after;

There are 2 ways of applying your max level seed to your spawn.

1) Apply seed to a level 1 spawn.
2) Apply seed to a max level spawn.

in case 1, the newly evolved familiar have the chance to level up as this higher tier familiar which - as my understanding goes - have a higher rate of attribute increase per level up compared to the previous tier.

in case 2, the seed was levelled during its lower evolution state, and in my logic- lose out on this higher rate of attribute increase per level up as the higher tier.

Comment: the question is, although the method where 2 max level spawn+seed of the same tier are evolved together does yield you high stats... this may not be as high as if you do min level spawn + max level seed.

I'm looking for a confirmation of this, or for someone to disprove it

Comment: @DodgeNDive Ah. Now I understand. I will have to confirm this as i have no concrete answer to it.

Comment: @DodgeNDive Found it.

Answer (score 1):

It yields the same result. If you combine a level 70 into a level 1 and then level it to 70, or if you combine two level 70s.  In the end they will have identical stats.

Comment: Hi Scooter, this is not true. Please take a look at the Blood Brother wiki article for proof of my answer http://bloodbrothersgame.wikia.com/wiki/Evolution